# Create time counter with display with capacity for several hours

Tags: timer, counter, 7segmentdisplay

I am rather new to this and as part of a hobby project I'd like to end up with a simple display showing a time counter. Starting at 0 and going up from there, being able to support several hours (so showing seconds tick by, then minutes and finally hours). 
So maybe have six 7 segment displays, counting up. 
This would be powered 'from the wall', after transforming the voltage into the fitting value.

I have seen some circuits that use 7 segment displays along with 555 components to create some sort of timer circuits but they seem quite complex in terms of size and component number.

Is there a way, perhaps using some more advanced/complex components, that I could achieve what I want?

I'd like to avoid overly complex circuits that depend on precisely measured resistors and capacitors to create counters that tick with the rate of seconds.

Comment: "Any" microcontroller with a suitable display should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do that with discrete logic, an 555 for the second timer, and discrete 7-segment display drivers.

That will take dozens of components, hours to build, and will have pretty terrible accuracy.

Or, you can buy a cheap microcontroler board (e.g. a small Arduino-compatible board, or anything else), and do it in half an hour.

That will be significantly easier, and add a much more practical skill to your repertoire. Also, it might use far less power (the classical 555 isn't power-efficient at all, and with a microcontroller, you could also easily dim the displays, so that you can save even more power).

---

Personally, I see the 555 as an excellent example circuit for simple analog oscillation generators, and something that you can wire up at least once in your live to make something blink, or listen to a ca. 1 kHz square wave.

It should be used as an example for simple circuitry, that's all.

There's some legitimate usage, especially when dealing with a simple-to-define behaviour, see Finbarr's comment below, but I'd argue that for applications where you'd need to process your 555's output in a complicated way, a microcontroller will get the job done much much easier, and usually, more cost-effectively.

Comment: You say that.... but the fuel pump relay in my car has a 555 inside. It cuts off the fuel supply if it doesn't get regular pulses from the coil to show that the engine is running, e.g. after a collision.

Comment: @Finbarr The world never stops to amaze me! Wow! Yeah, I'll definitely edit my answer to reflect that!

Comment: @Finbarr done :)

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily argue that it's the best way to achieve that function!

Comment: The art is knowing the difference.. As much as I prefer to use a micro too, I have seen situations where people have spent an inordinate amount of time getting the mircro to behave properly under all conditions, especially power up and down to perform a function that a 555 and a couple of gates could have done in five minutes of design time. Plus all that ugly releasing and maintaining code version overheads.

Comment: @Trevor yeah; and "the difference" might very well be "how easy is it for **me** to build the required functionality". And there's a whole lot of people that really are gurus with analog oscillators, and discrete logic, and they could probably plug together that clock on breadboard in a minute. Me, I've never learned that stuff. To me, it looks like a very digital, very logic, very sequential problem, and we solve those in software... For someone else, this might look like 5 minutes in their favourite HDL + a CPLD to get the job done.

Comment: Don't fully agree on the code release/versioning overhead. That's the result of having a feature, namely, not having built imperfect immutable hardware if you find a bug in your design, or if the requirements change, or if you get smarter somehow.

Comment: Yup, and I agree this is definitely a job for a micro, with multiplexed displays etc, component count would be minimal and added functionality opportunities are huge.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ya I just remember how it worked at NCR back when. The paperwork involved for releasing it took longer than the code design in some cases. PLus you had to get five people together from different departments to sign off on it..

Comment: @Trevor and let me guess: departments were competing for budget...

Comment: @MarcusMüller always...  and you couldn't just go get them to sign off either, it had to be in a "release party" meeting.

Comment: @Trevor … now, only if those parties would have involved actual fun… I see your point. I really want to believe this might have gotten a little better, but I know at least defence folks that really are shocked when they learn that they've been selling devices to customers that they must deliver with an info about which software they use within that device, because, you know, getting some software for free doesn't mean you can act like it's your own... So my fear is that in reality, code releasing might be very complicated still, especially in certain sectors.